# log4net common appender settings

Tags: logging, log4net

Does anyone have any idea if it's possible to create some sort of common appender settings instead of repeating settings in every appender. For example I have 3 appenders defined:

```
<appender name="DefaultRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\General_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} [%thread] [%username] %-5level [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="DefaultWCFMessagesFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\Rest_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="DefaultSqlFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\Sql_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

As you can see, many settings are duplicated throughout appender sections (e.g. appendToFile, rollingStyle, datePattern, etc.).

Is it possible somehow to define common settings for appender that would apply to each section when defined. Something along the lines:

```
<appenderCommon>
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appenderCommon>
<appender name="DefaultRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\General_" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} [%thread] [%username] %-5level [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="DefaultWCFMessagesFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\Rest_" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="DefaultSqlFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Logs\MyProduct\Sql_" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I cannot find anything in documentation on this subject.

Comment: No, you can't do that, the log4net configuration system doesn't support it..

Answer (score 0):

You can't find any documentation on this because it is not supported by log4net. You can generate the with your own tooling or use code to make your configuration.